# AndroidAnnotations Eclipse configuration with ADT 23

Tags: android-annotations

Since ADT 23, there seems to have no way to add Annotation Processor Factory Path to projects:

No "Annotation Processing" item in Poject>Properties>Java Compiler.

Does anyone know how to add androidannotations-X.X.X-api.jar to the annnotaions processing in the last Eclipse ADT?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known [problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73798) of the ADT bundle, and will be fixed as of ADT 23.0.3. In the meantime, you can fix this by [downloading](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) a standard Eclipse distribution and [installing the ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) to that. Or if you want to use your existing ADT bundle, you can install the necessary JDT plugin as described [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1066#issuecomment-49600888).

Also please note that you do not have to add the *androidannotations-X.X.X-api.jar* as you written in the OP. You have to add the *androidannotations-X.X.X.jar* to the annotation processing factories and *androidannotations-X.X.X-api.jar* to your classpath (libs).

Comment: Argh seem to be continuously running my head against the wall today

Answer (score 1):

i am using ADT23 with Eclipse Luna.
Go to your project properties and select `Java Compiler` and select you `Compiler Compliance Level` to 1.6.
Then your `Annotation Processing` option will be enable.
Create a folder `compile-libs` in your project, where your `lib` folder and paste `jar` file `androidannotations-3.0.1.jar` this location `compile-libs\androidannotations-3.0.1.jar` .

Add `androidannotations-api-3.0.1.jar` in your project `libs\androidannotations-api-3.0.1.jar` .

Finally, you must add both file path in your Factory Path.
e.g `{Your Project}/compile-libs/androidannotations-3.0.1.jar` and 
    `{Your Project}/libs/androidannotations-api-3.0.1.jar`

Comment: This is not answering the question. The problem here is the ADT 23 bundle does not has the `Annotation Processing` at all, because of a bug introduced in the bundle, which will be resolved in the next version.